# image resize without memory

Tags: image, image-resizing

i have implemented a few years ago an algorithm for resize image in and i forgot the name of it - i would be very happy if someone could remind me this name.
the method is to look on the input image center and on the output image ( thos that we want to derivative from the input image) center.
The output line equation will be :
OutputlineNum =(LineCounter - OutputImageCenter)* Scale + InputImageCenter

does it sounds familiar to some one?
the name was something like - double differential samling...

Comment: This is probably the weirdest question I've read

Answer (score 0):

Upscaling image is usually done with a bilinear or bicubic filter. There are fancier "super resolution" methods. The basic algorithm just samples the input image for every destination pixel using a convolution filter.